# Collatz sequence - minuses error

Tags: c#

The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

n → n/2 (n is even)

n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)

Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:

13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1

It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 
10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.

Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

This is my solution for the problem at hand.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int possCounter = 0;
    int largestChain = 0;
    int largestChainNum = 0;
    int chainNum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 999999; i++)
    {
        chainNum = i;
        possCounter = 1;
        while (chainNum != 1)
        {
            if (chainNum % 2 == 0)
            {
                chainNum = chainNum / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                chainNum = (3 * chainNum) + 1;
            }
            possCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine(chainNum);
        }
        if (possCounter > largestChain)
        {
            largestChainNum = i;
            largestChain = possCounter;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(largestChainNum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I placed the `Console.WriteLine(chainNum)` after `possCounter++` just to check if my code was running correctly. It would run correctly, however, at a certain point it started to run off **negative numbers**. I am not sure where I have gone wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Integer Overflow. If you use a larger type (like Long) instead, it should work fine.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When solving the problem (tracking the sequences) you'll run into number

```
56991483520
```

which is bigger than `int.MaxValue` and thus you'll have an *overflow*; I suggest using `long` for sequence members. One optimization tip more is to update by *series* of sequence items: having tracked

```
13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
```

you know the lengths for `40`, `20` and `16` and have no need to compute for these numbers again

```
private static Dictionary<long, int> s_Counts = new Dictionary<long, int>() {
  {1, 1},
};

private static void AppendCounts(long n) {
  List<long> list = new List<long>();

  for (; !s_Counts.ContainsKey(n); n = n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1) 
    list.Add(n);

  int count = s_Counts[n];

  for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    s_Counts.Add(list[i], count + list.Count - i);
}

...

for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; ++i)
  AppendCounts(i);

KeyValuePair<long, int> max = new KeyValuePair<long, int>(0, 0);

foreach (var pair in s_Counts)
  if (pair.Value > max.Value)
    max = pair;

Console("{0} generates {1} values", max.Key, max.Value);
```

The outcome is

```
837799 generates 525 values
```